# How to static import a class from default package?

Tags: java, oop

I have 2 classes: class A and class B, both classes are packageless (in default package). I want to import and use A's static variable into B. How do I do that so that it compiles?

The following is not compiling:

**A.java**

```
public class A {
    public static int x = 10;
}
```

**B.java**

```
import static A.x;

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

**Compiler output:**
B.java:1: error: static import only from classes and interfaces

Comment: *How do I do that so that it compiles?* You remove the import and write `A.x`, **or** you start using packages. **Why** aren't you putting your code into packages?

Comment: You can't, which is one of reasons why we shouldn't place classes in default package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is impossible with java**, you have to package them in a unique or different package.

Or you can use :

```
System.out.println(A.x);
```

You can read more in java doc about [Import Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html)